# Get date creation of a text file

Tags: c#, date-format

I wrote a piece of code in c# to get the date of creation of a text file and to have the date in `yyyyMMddHHMMSS` format  :

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("test.txt");
DateTime fileCreatedDate = fileInfo.CreationTime;
string dateCreation = fileCreatedDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHMMSS");
```

But it didn't work, `dateCreation` is for example: `201401291001SS`

How can I modify it ?

Comment: what do you mean by `"didn't work"`?

Comment: I have edited your question to show an incorrect result which you should provide always if possible. Otherwise it's difficult to help if we don't even know the problem (in this case it was easy to see).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have uppercase minutes which are months, use `mm`  (and `ss`) instead:

```
string dateCreation = fileCreatedDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

MM refers two digit month

mm refers two digit minutes

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("test.txt");
DateTime fileCreatedDate = fileInfo.CreationTime;
string dateCreation = fileCreatedDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("test.txt");
```

I think you forget to add your path. Refer to below example:

```
 string path = @"yourpath\test.txt";
 FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
```

And then:

```
string dateCreation = fileCreatedDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Comment: I hope I could understand your problem by "Not Working" Statment

Comment: FYI, the [`FileInfo`-constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts relative file names.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @TimSchmelter . I knew it but I couldn't understand what was his problem on running this code exactly because he didn't mention about it. Any way thanks for the information sharing

Answer (score 1):

```
//Take a file 
DateTime creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\CC.txt");
//Print
Response.Write(creationTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("test.txt");
DateTime fileCreatedDate = fileInfo.CreationTime;
string date = fileCreatedDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```